# Function already defined error in C

Tags: c

I have header file called `helper.h` which needed to be included in `main1.c` and `main2.c` so I included `helper.h` file in both files (without inclusion I was getting error) but still I'm getting error that functions in `helper.h` are already defined. How to get rid of this error using #ifndef?

Comment: can you show the content of the .h file?

Comment: Don't put the definition of the function in `helper.h` as the `ifndef` only prevents multiple inclusion in a single translation unit.

Comment: Are you using [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) at all?

Comment: @hmjd: Or, if you must put a function definition in a header, make it `static inline`, or thereabouts.  You're right; it is unusual and usually wrong to define a function in a header in C.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, thanks would never have considered that. However, I thought `inline` is a request to the compiler as opposed to an instruction to the compiler (i.e. not guaranteed) ?

Comment: @hmjd: Yes, it is a request.  The rules are  modestly complex (and I'd not claim expert status on `inline` in C), but my understanding is that if the compiler can't inline the function, it will create an actual function, and if it is static, that won't be visible outside the source file, so it does limited damage (the 'damage' being that you might have multiple copies of the non-inlined function body in the program, but you'd have had multiple copies of it had it been inlined, so the net damage is minimal).

Answer (score 3):

That indicates that you have *defined* a function in the header, i.e. implemented it. You can't do that, you should only have declarations i.e. *prototypes*.

Add a new C file `helper.c` which implements the functions.

Then compile each C file and link them together (`main1.o` + `helper.o` and `main2.o` + `helper.o`) to form the two programs.

Comment: Well, you _can_ do it (if, for example, only one C file includes the header file), but it's rather unwise :-) Perhaps "shouldn't" would be a better choice of word.

Answer (score 1):

In helper.h file add following lines at start

```
#ifndef HELPER_H
#define HELPER_H
```

I hope this should solve your problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This mechanism, plus the matching `#endif` at the end, prevents the header from being included twice in a single translation unit (TU).  However, the problem in the question appears to be that when two separate TUs each include the header, a function is defined twice.  That suggests the function is defined in the header, and the multiple inclusion prevention mechanism won't help here.